# GUI installer for memcached on Mac?

Tags: php, terminal, memcached, osx-lion, installation

I'm looking for a way to install memcached on my Mac running Lion, but I have no idea how to use terminal. Is there an easy to use GUI package to install it instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy GUI for installing [memcached](/questions/tagged/memcached) server. You can use an OSX package manager, like [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), but will still need to use terminal. I'd recommend installing everything from source, as this is a good introduction to how the underlying UNIX system works.

### Install trough package manager

#### HomeBrew

```
$ brew install memcached
```

#### Macports

```
$ sudo port install memcached
```

### Install from source

#### 1. Install XCode from AppStore

XCode will install the basic libraries and applications to compile source code into an executable application. XCode was shipped on the install disc that came with your Mac, but is now available for free download in the AppStore. Additional set-up will be needed, depending on your version of XCode.

#### 2. Install autconfig, automake, libevent, and then memcached

Memcached will require a few dependencies; which, is handled automatically by the listed package managers. Each dependencies & memcached follow the same Terminal commands to install: `./configure`, `make`, and `make install`. This becomes very easy with experience. Here's an example.

```
# Download source
$ curl -O http://memcached.googlecode.com/files/memcached-1.4.14.tar.gz

# Extract files
$ tar zvxf memcached-1.4.14.tar.gz

# Change working directory to newly extracted files
$ cd memcached-1.4.14

# Configure source to your local machine
$ ./configure

# Compile the application
$ make

# Install application on your system
$ sudo make install
```

Heres' where you can find the needed libraries & such

- Autoconfig http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
- AutoMake  http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-1.12.3.tar.gz
- LibEvent https://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-2.0.19-stable.tar.gz
- Memcached http://memcached.googlecode.com/files/memcached-1.4.14.tar.gz